# Keeping first word and remove the remaining word in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string

```
str = "Batman is not batman without alfred batman"
```

I need to remove all instances of `batman` (**case insensitive**), but keep batman if and only if it is the first word of the string.

Some examples:

```
Batman is not batman without alfred batman #=> Batman is not without alfred
## first batman is kept, remaining batman is removed.

batman joker BATMAN robin batMan catwoman #=> batman joker robin catwoman 
## removes all other batman instances and keep only the first batman because it is the first word.

joker batMaN alfred batmobile batman #=> joker alfred batmobile
## removes all batman instances because batman is not the first word.
```

The case of first batman instance doesn't matter.

I tried `str.gsub(/(batman)+/i,"")`, but it removes all instances instead. How can I keep `batman` if and only if it is the first word in the sentence, and remove other `batman`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.gsub!(/(?i)(?<!^)batman/, '')
```

`(?i)` case insensitive

`(?<!^)` lookbehind that the start of the line is not immediately before it

Comment: This returns `"Batman is not  without alfred ", leaving an extra space after `'not'` and `'alfred'`. The OP's examples show those extra spaces being removed.

Answer (score 2):

And here is a non-regexp version:

```
str.split.delete_if.with_index do |word,index|
  index > 0 and word.downcase == "batman"
end.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to remove all `batman`s that are preceded by a space.

```
str.gsub!(/ batman/i, '')
```

In action:

```
str = 'batman joker BATMAN robin batMan catwoman'
=> "batman joker BATMAN robin batMan catwoman"
str.gsub!(/ batman/i, '')
=> "batman joker robin catwoman"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Batman is not batman without alfred, batman's batmanman"

str.gsub(/\sbatman\b/i, '')
  #=> "Batman is not without alfred,'s batmanman"
```

The word break `\b` is needed to avoid returning

```
"Batman is not without alfred,'s man"
```